# Is the alt attribute for img tag in HTML not supported by Safari on Windows?

Tags: html, windows, safari

When I use the `alt` attribute with `img` tag in Safari on Windows, instead of displaying the alternate text, Safari only shows a "?" in a box. Is this a bug in Safari on Windows, or Safari is missing this feature.

Comment: A code sample here would help us to reproduce your issue.

Comment: check the link http://rebuildingtheweb.com/en/how-should-browsers-render-alt-text/ that john gave. it documents the thing I pointed out in detail

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every browser has its own magical way of rendering alternate text. It seems to be a standards issue, hopefully to be resolved in the future HTML5 specs.

IE, Firefox, & Opera render the alternative text inside IMG for broken images. Chrome & Safari also do this, but **the text will be cutoff you unless you set the height/weight of the image**.

Here is an excellent article on the issue (with screen caps that show how each browser renders the alt text).

[http://rebuildingtheweb.com/en/how-should-browsers-render-alt-text/](http://web.archive.org/web/20180228025808/http://rebuildingtheweb.com/en/how-should-browsers-render-alt-text/)

More screenies from the Paceillo Group's blog...
[http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/misc/HTML5/alt-tests/screenshots.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20141129052628/http://files.paciellogroup.com/blogmisc/HTML5/alt-tests/screenshots.html)
[http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/?p=498](http://web.archive.org/web/20170721022419/https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2010/01/alt-and-title-content-display-in-popular-browsers/)

Comment: @John thanks for a great answer and the rebuildingtheweb link.

Answer (score 5):

Never use `alt` for rendering tooltips. Use `title` instead. It is supported by almost all browsers. `alt` is meant to be an alteranative text which should come only if the image is unavailable/cannot be displayed or for some Assistive technologies like screen readers while reading the page.

Comment: Just discovered the Android browser doesn't display title on img :(( http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5836